# Excel Dynamic Web Query (Simple Problem!)

Tags: html, macos, dynamic, excel-web-query

I'm trying to import a simple HTML table from a website into EXCEL on an iMac

I wrote a text file saved as .iqy

```
WEB
1
https://english.mubasher.info/countries/kw/stock-prices

Selection=1
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

What I get is this:

```
Stock   Price   Change %    Change  Turnover    Volume  Open    High    Low

{{row.name | limitTo : 20}} {{row.value}}   {{row.changePercentage}}    {{row.change}}  {{row.turnover}}    {{row.volume}}  {{row.open}}    {{row.high}}    {{row.low}}
```

How do I get it to fetch the actual data? (entire table)

Comment: Why you just copy paste it?

Comment: Supposedly this is a dynamic web query meaning it changes the values automatically as the website updates.

Comment: Ok, now understand.
I don't have knowledge about.
But i will search.

Comment: Hello, have you found any solution?